# convert input stream to json to display

Tags: android, json

i want the the data received as input stream from my page to be converted into json and not string as it is being converted. 
can anyone please edit my code so that i can impress my PL. i really need to finish it.

```
The Code:

     // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result ;
}

 private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

Comment: `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static JSONObject convertInputStreamToJSONObject(InputStream inputStream)
        throws JSONException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return new JSONObject(result); }
```

That will do it.

Comment: if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToJSONObject(inputStream);
     
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

Comment: Edited the answer for handling a JSONException, can you give a trace of why didn't work? Thanks!